# Error in ansible with_items while creating a target group on AWS cloud

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a target group on AWS cloud. My ansible script properly finds the two instance ids that need to be attached to the target group but somehow my create target group couldn't find the item variable value.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{item}}"
  with_items: "{{instance_ids}}" 


- name: Create a target group with instance targets
  community.aws.elb_target_group:
    name: duboisTestTargetGroup
    protocol: http
    port: 80
    vpc_id: "{{vpc_id}}"
    health_check_protocol: http
    health_check_path: /
    successful_response_codes: "200,250-260,302"
    state: present
    wait_timeout: 200
    wait: True    
    targets:
      - Id: "{{item}}"
        Port: 80
    with_items: "{{instance_ids}}"
```

The output is

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=i-04c8af3e7d54a86e7) => {
    "msg": "i-04c8af3e7d54a86e7"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=i-06c517c6b3e2b79b5) => {
    "msg": "i-06c517c6b3e2b79b5"
}

TASK [Create a target group with instance targets] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/Users/dot/Programs/python_programs/ansible/DuboisGoldTest/tasks/vpc/create_loadbalancer.yml': line 43, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Create a target group with instance targets\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the indentation of `with_items` in the `elb_target_group` task. While it is fine in the `debug` task.

Aligning `with_items` *with the task*, instead of `targets`, should populate the `item`, like below:

```yaml
  - name: Create a target group with instance targets
    community.aws.elb_target_group:
      name: duboisTestTargetGroup
      protocol: http
      port: 80
      vpc_id: "{{ vpc_id }}"
      health_check_protocol: http
      health_check_path: /
      successful_response_codes: "200,250-260,302"
      state: present
      wait_timeout: 200
      wait: True
      targets:
        - Id: "{{ item }}"
          Port: 80
    with_items: "{{ instance_ids }}"
```

Comment: I tried this and this created updates the target in the target group with the last instance_id.

Comment: Can you try setting `modify_targets: False`?